# Git - How to change one line of source code of an old commit and propagate changes to all upstream commits?

Tags: git, rebase

The situation is that I have a repository with .cs file containing a test string equal to a curse word.
Like:

```
string test = "very bad curse word";
```

and it was added to repository on 5th commit but then 1000s more commits were made.

It's not an option to simply change that word and make a new commit because that bad word will still be in all previous commits.

Maybe there is some sort of special rebase or other git technique where I can go back to that initial problematic commit where that test string was created originally, change only that commit, make a rebase and that word would be gone forever?

Comment: I'm thinking `filter-branch` might be helpful, but I'm not confident

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely a bad pratice! .. however, if you really want to do that, then you can edit the concerned commit by running an interactive rebase and rewriting your git history.

First get the SHA1 of the commit right before the concerned one and do:
`git rebase -i SHA1`. Then in the rebase editor, change the first word from `pick` to `edit` (or `e`) on the line indicating the commit you want to change (it should be the very first line). Save and exit.

From there, modify your file and run `git add -u` to add it to staged changes. Then, run `git commit --amend`, `git rebase --continue` to complete the rebase (be aware that, depending on the changes, you may have to resolve conflicts).

Finally, run `git push -f origin master` (assuming your branch is master) to upload your changes to the remote.

!!! NOTE: the option `-f` tells git to force push to the remote. Since you rewrote the whole history from the changed commit:

- your co-workers will no longer be able to push to the remote. I mean, they will have to retrieve the forced changes first.
- you will lose any tags you made.
- maybe aome other "cons" ..

This is really a bad practice and not something to go easy with. Think twice before doing such things ..

Comment: If there are any merges in the history after that commit, OP will need to add the option `--merge-rebases` to the rebase call, otherwise this is a good answer.

Comment: @joanis, thank you! I do not know about this option.. feel free to update my answer with this improvement :)

Comment: @joanis `--rebase-merges` :-)

Comment: @phd. Oops, right. Diswordic? :) I even did `git rebase -h` before typing that, yet still managed to get it backwards.

Comment: @Jib when you do a rebase, by default all the merge commits are skipped and you just get a linear history. Sometimes that's ok, but sometimes you want to recreate the original graph with all its merges too. To do that, you add `--rebase-merges`.

Comment: @joanis thanks for the clarification, personally I do rebase before merge so I never ran into such but I will definitely bare this in mind for the future!

Comment: @Jib I rarely use this option as I do my best to only rebase work in progress and indeed stuff that hasn't been merged yet. But this question is a different scenario, which will likely require rebasing merges too. Big history rewrites are the typical use case for this option in my experience. As you say, these are not best practice and are only done when really necessary (like removing secrets, or profanity! from the history) and so rebasing merges rarely actually comes up.