How do I amend a commit that's already been pushed
I made some changes to a file and committed it with a descriptive commit message, and pushed it to the origin. A few seconds later, I discovered a typo in the same file and fixed it. I decided to amend the last commit rather than add a new commit, since I don't like polluting my history with extraneous commits.
Unfortunately, pushing it again results in a conflict upstream since my local amended commit disagrees with the one I had just pushed. I don't understand how to merge. Even if I did know how, presumably it creates yet another needless merge commit.
Last time this happened I resolved it with a forced push which is frowned upon in a team setting. It is odd Git gives no warning when using the seemingly innocuous --amend commit option.
How do I resolve this conflict in a polite and clean way. Also, what should I do next time I amend a commit that's already been pushed?

How did you fix the typo?

I am not sure what I am seeing here. Can you post the full session starting with git push ?

Does this thread answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75034710/20124358

@jlp Not really. It doesn't describe how to prevent and resolve the conflict.

@EugeneSh. The error is based on something I did wrong because I'm bad at resolving conflicts. Yes, I have trouble getting along with Git.

@KamilCuk Using the editor and saving the file.

"Last time this happened I resolved it with a forced push which is frowned upon." Frowned upon by who? Are you in a team? If so, don't let them just frown, ask why it is not allowed. The reason not to force push is to avoid breaking history of shared long-lived branches. But on a feature branch you're working alone on? Force-push to your heart's content.

What file? Any file has no effect on commits. Did you edit some file inside .git directory? You should have used git rebase, didn't you use any git command?

@KamilCuk If I got it right, OP spotted a typo in the committed content after having committed and pushed. Then corrected the faulty file then did a commit --amend but the first version with the typo is still on remote.

@RomainValeri Yes.

I edited my question. I thought I was exceedingly clear.

If you are working on a feature branch, especially a branch that has not yet been submitted as a PR, that branch (under all sensible workflows) belongs entirely to you. It does not constitute shared material. No one else will know or care if you push with force.
So, assuming that what happened is something like this:
git branch myFeature
# edit, add, commit... edit, add, commit...
git push origin myFeature
git commit --amend

...it is perfectly reasonable to say:
git push --force origin myFeature

That is a reasonably "polite and clean way" to reshape the history of this feature branch, which only you are working on, and which therefore belongs entirely to you. But it is not necessarily the politest and cleanest thing you could do. Read on...


It is odd Git gives no warning when using the seemingly innocuous --amend commit option.

No, it isn't. Not if you know what Git is. Git is a directed graph of commits (each commit having at least one parent). Once created, a commit is completely immutable. There is no such thing as editing a commit. That is a necessary rule, because otherwise Git would not be doing its job, which is to preserve history.
The simple and direct way to use Git is therefore just to keep moving forward. Make more commits! If you have pushed a commit and you then discover there was a mistake in one of the files, fix the mistake, add, and commit! The new commit fixes the mistake in the old commit, and the overall state of the project is improved. Now push, to save your commit to the server. The server simply adds it on to the tip of the existing history of this branch.
When you say --amend, on the other hand, you are proposing to change history. You cannot rewrite the existing commit; you are making a brand new commit, in the place in the history where the old commit used to be. If you have already pushed the old commit, there is now a fundamental disagreement about the history between you and the server; you say a certain commit goes into a certain "slot" in the history, and the server says a different commit goes into that slot. That's an irreconcilable difference, so you have to use force to push.

So, to sum up, here are your choices:

Just keep moving forward. Edit, add, commit, push, over and over and over.

If you feel, on the other hand, that you might want to rewrite history within your feature branch, and you don't like force-pushing then don't push your branch as you work on it. Just work on the branch until it's ready, and then push it.

Or, just accept the fact that if you do push the branch and you do then rewrite its history, you have to use force in order to push it the next time.


